# Проблема с компиляцией Cython

Tags: cython

Всем привет. Я, как и многие, не хочу просто так писать Python-код, я хочу также делать EXE-приложения. Я уже добился многого, написал приложение на Pygame, скомпилировал его в EXE, сделал NSIS-установщик. Однако надо мной нависла проблема открытости исходников - любой  может взять decompyle и расковырять мои .PYC-файлы. И тут на помощь пришёл Cython (не путать с CPython), который компилируется в DLL (PYD) и не декомпилируем (чемпион по вскрытию исходников при помощи декомпилятора всё же его вскроет, но шанс всё же очень мал). Заковырка в том, что я всё сделал как по инструкции, но "в огороде не растёт" - выдал ошибку. Вот мой компиляторный скрипт Cython:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
  name = 'JoyMonitorMain',
  ext_modules = cythonize("joymonitor.pyx"),
)
```

И вот ошибка:

```
joymonitor.pyx:16:12: Expected an identifier
Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "cythonise.py", line 6, in <module>
         ext_modules = cythonize("joymonitor.pyx"),
       File "C:\Program Files\Python34\lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line
 934, in cythonize
         cythonize_one(*args)
       File "C:\Program Files\Python34\lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line
 1056, in cythonize_one
         raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
     Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: joymonitor.pyx
```

Запускал я скрипт компиляции в командной строке командой:

`python cythonise.py build_ext --inplace`

---

На всякий случай скажу, что я не пользовался Cython-ом ранее. И в <strike>моём</strike> коде может встречаться бред для C, который является синтаксисом Python 3, например, строковые литералы `'замечательная строка про погоду'` вместо `"замечательная строка про погоду"`. Имеет ли это значение для Cython?

---

Я проверил код и почитал документацию - мой код совместим с Cython. Но я так и не понимаю, что это за ошибка? Что ему не нравится?

Comment: а если просто  использовать py2exe?

Comment: @nick_gabpe Слышал я про некоторые условности, неудобства и заковырки с py2exe. cx_Freeze изначально разрабатывался как "следующая ступень в эволюции" py2exe и встроенной утилиты Freeze. С cx_Freeze у меня есть опыт работы, с py2exe - нет.

Comment: Позанудствую: как правило никому ваш код не нужен и взламывать его вряд ли будут, а если очень захотят, ничего не поможет. Реально защитить свой код от взлома возможно только выполняя его на сервере :)

Comment: В любом случае DLL-ы и PYC-и - не самая простая жертва для взлома.

Comment: Что удивительно, я почти через месяц существования вопроса заметил первую строку трейсбека! Почему питон так любит ругаться на определение функций в классе с именем, идентичным имени одной из встроенных функций (строка 16 - такое определение в классе)? Ещё я заметил, что если просто открывать код в командной строке с автоматическим подбором подходящей программы, то он выдаёт ЭТУ ошибку, а если запускать через `python` (указан в PATH), то ошибки нет!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На самом деле проблема заключалась в первой строке ошибки:

```
joymonitor.pyx:16:12: Expected an identifier
```

Это такая незаметная система выдавать ошибки ситонизации. Да, так незаметно: эта первая строчка просто незаметна, когда пробегаешься глазами по traceback-у. У меня как у любителя Visual Studio, C# и .NET (помимо чистого Python) это вызывает недоумение. Но всё же это re`raise` с записью в `stderr`, это не может быть читаемым. При использовании Cython этот вывод ошибок перевода нужно учитывать. После устранения ошибки, конечно, ситонизатор заработал.